# Yii echmultiselect not filtering multiselect

Tags: php, yii, widget, cgridview, jquery-ui-multiselect

i'm having problems with echmultiselect in my project, it doesn't filter at all and inhibits other column filters already working.

View

```
    array ( 
            'name'=>'typeSelectedName',
            'value'=>'$data->typeSelected->name',
            'filter'=> $this->widget('EchMultiselect', array(
                'model' => $model,
                'dropDownAttribute' => 'typeSelectedName',
                'dropDownHtmlOptions'=> array(
                     'style'=>'width:225px;',
                     'multiple'=>true,
           ),
          'data' => array('A'=>'A','B'=>'B','C'=>'C','Z'=>'Z','X'=>'X','K'=>'K','T'=>'T'),
           'options' => array(
                'header'=> Yii::t('EchMultiSelect.EchMultiSelect',''),
                'buttonWidth' => 80, 
                'position'=>array('my'=>'left bottom', 'at'=>'left top'),
                'ajaxRefresh' => true,  
                'multiselect'=>true,
                'filter'=>true,
           ),
         ),
       true // capture output; needed so the widget displays inside the grid
     ),
   ),
```

Model

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
    if(!empty($this->type)) {
       foreach($this->type as $v) {
             $criteria->compare('type', $v, false, 'OR');
                    }
            }
    $criteria->compare('sa_id',$this->sa_id,true);
```

...

i am using yii 1.1.13 and i can see this Cgridview:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your dropdown attribute in multyselect is `typeSelectedName` while in the model file for criteria you check `type` attribute.
2. The multyselect makes an ajax call; so you need to check it and what kind of data are passed in it.

Better you add some options inside multiselect to invoke custom ajax for model filtering: upon returned data do update grid. This way multyselect will be working as the only filter option (no other options will be taken into account); though you might get form data thru `this.form.serialize()` and make joined filtering.

Comment: @Carlos M, how about my 2nd point of ajax call? have you fixed dropdown attribute name?

Comment: _i followed these instructions_ http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/echmultiselect/
but i can't get this working and when i change in dropdown attribute `typeSelectedName` into `type` it shows me an error

Other idea i was using without the widget:
`array(
                    'name'=>'typeSelectedName',
                    'value'=>'$data->typeSelected->name',
                    'filter'=>array('A B Z X K','A B Z','T C'),
                    )` but don't know how to configure
`$criteria->compare('type',$this->type, true,'OR');` in order to get all rows with those values in **type** column

Comment: @CarlosM, yes, `type` is a bad name for an attribute. Can you rewrite/redefine this attribute in the model?